# How to compare number of records if data is empty after Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem to compare my records after ajax call. So I created standard ajax call where I send parameters, I use these parameter to get records from my query. If I do not have any records I want to execute my next step, if not I will output alert. Here is code that I used:

```
$j.ajax({
    type:  'POST'
    , url:  'Records.html'
    , cache:  false
    , data: {'myQyery':sel,'myID':myID}
    , async:   false
    , success:  function(data)
        {
            var jsData = JSON.parse("{" + $j.trim(data).slice(0,-1) + "}");

            for( var key in jsData){
                if(jsData[key].duplicateID == ''){
                    alert('Run my code')    
                }else{
                    alert('You already signed in.')
                }
            }

        }
   , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ gwLogIt(errorThrown)}
});
```

If I run this code and I have records after my Ajax call, my code works fine. Response looks like this:

```
"1":{"duplicateID":"8"},
```

and I get my second alert. But If I do not have any records after my Ajax call, my first alert never get executed. My response is completely blank without any records. So I tried to compare my data equal to '' but that did not work. What is the other way to compare if my data is empty after ajax call? That way my first if statement can be executed?

Comment: Check for the existence of keys with `Object.keys(jsData).length`.

Comment: Why not try getting the `length` of data, and if it is 0 you know it is empty?

Comment: Synchronous calls are a bad idea.

Comment: What else I should use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for `jsData[key].duplicateID == ''` I used `if(Object.keys(jsData).length == 0)`. This way if I do not have any records returned my data is equal 0.